# Why can't I perform conditionals on environment variables in a node.js application

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

When I execute this node.js application...

```
if(process.env.ENV_ARG === "someValue") {
    console.log("conditional works...");
} else {
    console.log(`ENV_ARG => ${process.env.ENV_ARG}`);
}
```

with the following script...

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "SET ENV_ARG=someValue && node index.js"
  },
```

the output is:

```
ENV_ARG => someValue
```

I can't understand why the if statement evaluates to false. 
When the contents of `process.env.ENV_ARG` are logged in the else-block, they should be accessible for the if statement above...at least I thought so...
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have a windows machine at hand, but I can't reproduce that on Linux. Can you try logging `console.log(\`"${process.env.ENV_ARG}"\`)`?

Comment: logging the variable with quotes made the problem visible. It was the script. I had to change it from `"SET ENV_ARG=someValue && node index.js"` to `"SET ENV_ARG=someValue&& node index.js"`. The space before the && operator was evaluated as part of the variable-content. -- Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of spacing. There is a space that gets included at the end of the environment variable.

One way to work around it is the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "SET ENV_ARG=someValue&& node index.js"
  },
```

Comment: Gosh, I spent so much of time to get the root cause. Thanks to you for clearing things out.